# find chromatic polynomial of $K_{3,3}$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

> find chromatic polynomial of $K_{3,3}$ - full connected $3-3$ bipartite

### my solution

I have considered $9$ cases:

- Left side is colored using $1$ color AND right using $1$ color
- Left side is colored using $1$ color AND right using $2$ colors
- Left side is colored using $1$ color AND right using $3$ colors
- Left side is colored using $2$ colors AND right using $1$ color
- Left side is colored using $2$ colors AND right using $2$ colors
- Left side is colored using $2$ colors AND right using $3$ colors
- Left side is colored using $3$ color AND right using $1$ color
- Left side is colored using $3$ color AND right using $2$ colors
- Left side is colored using $3$ color AND right using $3$ colors

I got such result:

$$ f(t) = (t-2) (t-1) ((t-5) (t-4) (t-3)+3 (t-4) (t-3)+(t-3)) t+3 (t-1) ((t-4) (t-3) (t-2)+3 (t-3) (t-2)+(t-2)) t+((t-3) (t-2) (t-1)+3 (t-2) (t-1)+(t-1)) t $$

that gives me
$$f(t) = -31 t + 78 t^2 - 75 t^3 + 36 t^4 - 9 t^5 + t^6 $$

some first values:
$$f(1) = 0 \\ f(2) = 2 \\ f(3) = 42 \\ f(4) = 420 $$

Comment: The polynomial you have agrees with my computations.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3333127/find-chromatic-polynomial-of-a-graph-k-n-m?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

It can be boiled down to 3 cases only:

Case 1: All vertices on the left have a different color, thus all vertices on the right can choose from $t-3$ colors
$$t(t-1)(t-2)(t-3)^3$$
Case 2: Choose two vertices on the left to share a color $\binom{3}{2}=3$, the remaining vertex on the left will have a different color, hence all the vertices on the right side can choose from $t-2$ colors
$$3t(t-1)(t-2)^3$$
Case 3: All vertices on the left share the same color
$$t(t-1)^3$$

We get then
$$t(t-1)(t-2)(t-3)^3 + 3t(t-1)(t-2)^3 + t(t-1)^3 = t^6 -9t^5 + 36t^4 -75t^3 + 78t^2 -31t$$